# How does spark determine the preferredLocation of an RDD in repartition and coalesce?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

When does an RDD get it's preferred location? How is the preferred location determined?
I've seen some weird behaviors in repartition and coalesce I could not quite make sense of: 
1. When coalescing form n to n-1 partitions, I see spark just coalesce one partition to another single partition. (I think the ideal behavior would be evenly distribute to all n-1 nodes)

2. When run repartition I see spark repartition such that one node have multiple partition of rdds.

Does the above behavior have something to do with preferedLocations?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `rdd.repartition(n)` just calls `rdd.coalesce(n, shuffle = true)`, so we're just comparing shuffle true vs false.

#### shuffle = false

In this mode, Spark constructs a new RDD whose partitions contain one or more partitions of the parent RDD -- if you coalesce from `n` partitions -> `n/2` partitions, then each partition consists of the elements from two semi-random partitions in the parent.  This mode is appropriate when you want to reduce partitioning and the partitions are already balanced, like when you've done a filter that affects elements in each partition roughly equally.  The overhead is very low.  Also, note that it's impossible to increase number of partitions with this mode.

#### shuffle = true

For some background, I recommend [this blog post](https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/) for learning a bit more about how and why we shuffle.  The fundamental differences in this execution mode are:

- higher overhead (all data is transmitted over network)
- good for rebalancing partitions (if you perform a filter that drops out either all elements in a partition or none, then `shuffle=false` will produce imbalanced partitions, but `shuffle=true` will resolve the issue)
- can increase the number of partitions

Preferred locations don't have much to do with it -- you're seeing preferred locations only in the `shuffle = false` mode because the locality is preserved without shuffles, but after a shuffle the original preferredLocations are irrelevant (replaced with new preferred locations about shuffle destinations).